# Is there a way on MSE to search for previously asked questions using LaTeX code?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, search

Before I post a question, I always try to see if it has been previously posted. But for some questions with mostly "math symbols" and few words, I find it difficult to search effectively. For example, if I tried to search MSE for

"Show that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log x}{1+x^2}dx=0$",

what should I type into the search bar? Is there a way to search with LaTeX, and if not, why not? Also, I am not sure how to tag this question. Thanks!

Comment: Related older posts: [How do you search for specific questions?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/how-do-you-search-for-specific-questions), [Search queries involving symbols and/or TeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6180/search-queries-involving-symbols-and-or-tex), [How do you search for duplicates](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3258/how-do-you-search-for-duplicates) and perhaps also some other posts you can find there (among linked questions).

Comment: ...and maybe also other questions tagged [search+mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search+mathjax).

Comment: In case you were actually looking for that question, try [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/916973/23353) with $b=1$.